# Ubuntu 14.04 Broken package issue

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have tried to install TreeSheets on my Ubuntu 14.04, using following method.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

added : deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install treesheets
```

Source : http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/wily/universe/t/treesheets/install/index.html

But, i ended up with lots of issue, (because it was for Ubuntu 15.04) and then i tried to resolve my issue using following command :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

But again the same error, i also tried

```
sudo dpkg -a --configure
```

But the same error as following :

```
Setting up lvm2 (2.02.122-1ubuntu1) ... update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found /etc/init.d/lvm2-lvmetad: 4: .: Can't open /lib/init/init-d-script invoke-rc.d: initscript lvm2-lvmetad, action "restart" failed. dpkg: error processing package lvm2 (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 Setting up cups-daemon (2.1.0-4ubuntu3) ... AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd at line 145: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CONDLISTID, expecting TOK_MODE update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match cups Default-Stop values (1) /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found start: Job failed to start invoke-rc.d: initscript cups, action "start" failed. dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:  cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.1.0-4ubuntu3); however: Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up fontconfig (2.11.1-0ubuntu6) ... Regenerating fonts cache... failed. See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information. dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:  cups depends on cups-core-drivers (>= 2.1.0-4ubuntu3); however:   Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.  cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.1.0-4ubuntu3); however:   Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:  libreoffice-core depends on fontconfig; however:   Package fontconfig is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-core (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-calc:  libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-calc (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:  python3-uno depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gnome:  libreoffice-gnome depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gnome (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gtk:  libreoffice-gtk depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gtk (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-draw:  libreoffice-draw depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-draw (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-writer:  libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-writer (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-impress:  libreoffice-impress depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.  libreoffice-impress depends on libreoffice-draw (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-draw is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-impress (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-math:  libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-math (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core:  libreoffice-base-core depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base-core (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120ubuntu6) ... update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic Errors were encountered while processing:  lvm2  cups-daemon  cups-core-drivers  fontconfig  cups  libreoffice-core  libreoffice-calc  python3-uno  libreoffice-gnome  libreoffice-gtk  libreoffice-draw  libreoffice-writer  libreoffice-impress  libreoffice-math  libreoffice-base-core
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.